# CSS: How to center text over an image, both always centered and proportional regardless of window size

Tags: css

It seems like this should be easy but I have wasted countless days trying to make it work. I need a paragraph of text centered over a square image. The difficulty is that I need them to always appear exactly proportional regardless of window size. So the image and text will always be fully visible, appearing centered in the window regardless of window size. One other difficulty: I can't use vmin or vmax because the Android browser can't handle it. Any sage wisdom out there that can help me out?

Comment: `text-align: center;` should work fine.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. The text and image will need to resize to always appear fully visible in the center of the window (both horizontally and vertically). I haven't been able to get it so that the text and image always appear in the exact orientation to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try googling css media queries. Here is a link to a good page. Adjust the width/height of the image based on the screen size. Here is a link to a reference: [w3c media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).

Comment: Thanks, I haven't heard of this before. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Many people also use it for mobile sites-which you may also consider.